# NSPredicate format evaluateWithObject with nsarray containing nsdictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, format, nspredicate

Is there any cookbook for NSPredicate format? I'm wonder how to **test** NSArray with dictionaries, if one of them contains a value "adult" for key "type" as shown in an example below:

```
NSDictionary* passengers = @[@{@"type":@"child"},@{@"type":@"adult"}];
NSPredicate* testPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.type LIKE[c] adult"];
BOOL adultOnBoard = [testPredicate evaluateWithObject: passengers];
```

DO NOT MIX WITH filtering array - **I expect testing as a "cheap" operation comparing to filtering**.

Comment: You have to do the same computational work to "test" as to "filter". The only difference is you may be able to stop sooner. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @JoshCaswell exactly - stop sooner, especially on big arrays may save time. for now using enumerateArray... with *stop flag, wonder, if I can do that with predicate.